# Is there a way for an SMTP server to respond that a user has moved to a new address?

Tags: smtp

Is there a way for an SMTP server to tell an MTA that a user has moved to a new address?

There are many [SMTP return codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMTP_server_return_codes), including for common situations like Mailboxes being full, the address not existing, the message being rejected etc.

Is there currently, or is there a proposal, to allow a server to respond to incoming mail with an error code that the user has changed email addresses and is now available at a new domain?

**Again, draft proposals are OK**. I've looked in [RFC 5321 section 4.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) and perhaps '251: user not local will forward' works but I'm not sure how email practically works in 2020.

**Use case**: users migrating between email providers is a common scenario and I can imagine having a grace period (where the old provider lets incoming MTAs know the user has moved to another address) has probably been discussed before.

**Example** a user was username@foo.com, but has have moved to bar.com. foo.com is happy to let incoming connections know that this identity is now at a different domain, and that senders should update their address books, for some period of time (say 12 months), before foo.com no longer provides any service for this identity at all.

Comment: Interesting concept. I think this kind of thing is generally done above thecsmtp level using forwarders and autoresponders (which are, of-course, not conducive to automatic updates for mua's)

Answer (score 4):

There are such status codes for both

- forwarding (`251  User not local; will forward to <forward-path>`) and
- rejecting (`551  User not local; please try <forward-path>`)

but they are intended for the *mail user agents* (MUA), not for other MTAs.

The [RFC 5321, 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-3.4) *Forwarding for Address Correction or Updating* explains these standard response codes that do have the **ability** to inform the sender about the new address. Emphasis is mine.

> Consequently,    the "forwarding" mechanisms described in Section
> 3.2 of RFC 821, and    especially the `251` (corrected destination) and `551` reply codes from    RCPT must be evaluated carefully by
> implementers and, when they are    available, by those configuring
> systems (see also [Section 7.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-7.4)).
>
> In particular:
>
> - Servers MAY forward messages when they are aware of an address
>   change.  When they do so, they MAY either provide address-updating
>   information with a `251` code, or may forward "silently" and return
>   a `250` code.  However, **if a `251` code is used, they MUST NOT assume
>   that the client will actually update address information or even
>   return that information to the user.**
>
> Alternately,
>
> - Servers MAY reject messages or return them as non-deliverable
>   when
>   they cannot be delivered precisely as addressed.  When they do so,
>   they MAY either provide address-updating information with a `551`
>   code, or may reject the message as undeliverable with a `550` code
>   and no address-specific information.  However, **if a `551` code is
>   used, they MUST NOT assume that the client will actually update
>   address information or even return that information to the user.**

The reality is that email addresses aren't really updated by the MUAs based on these status codes, probably because their authenticity has been hard to prove. I haven't seen these response codes widely in use anywhere, either.

There are also **practical problems with automatic email address updates**, as well as forwarding:

- If a user has changed the address because the old address gets a lot of spam, it wouldn't be wise to disclose the new contact information. That's for personal email addresses.
- With business email addresses the probable reason for address change is that the user has got a new job from another employer.

  - There's a problem to distinguish whether the email is addressed to the person or to his/her former position in the company. There would be a need to publish two new addresses, and that really can't be done with these error codes, as automatic update would be impossible without human desicion.
  - The old employer doesn't necessarily even know the new address. Furthermore, it might not be wise to point the clients to this new address, as it might point them towards a competitor.
  - Usually a sender will conclude that the person doesn't work there anymore, if the email just bounces with `550 mailbox unavailable`. Then, they will Google for a suitable address for their contact.

If you want to distinguish a mailbox that never existed from a mailbox that once existed but has been removed, you could use e.g. [RFC 3463](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3463#section-3.2) extended status code `X.1.6`:

> `X.1.6`   Destination mailbox has moved, No forwarding address
>
> The mailbox address provided was at one time valid, but mail is
> no longer being accepted for that address.  This code is only
> useful for permanent failures.

Finally, as mentioned in [RFC 5321, 2.3.7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-2.3.7):

> The general form of a reply is a numeric completion code
> (indicating failure or success) usually followed by a text string.
> The codes are for use by programs and the text is usually intended
> for human users.

**It would be wise to add a human readable explanation, e.g.**

```
550 5.1.6 Joe Bloggs has retired. See example.com/contact for a new representative.
```